# Set isolation.level = read_committed in Spring Kafka (Spring Boot version 1.5.18 and spring Kafka version 1.3.8)

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-kafka

I am setting up kafka transection manager using spring chained transection manager , and i have to set isolation.level = read_committed in Spring Kafka (Spring Boot version 1.5.18 and spring Kafka version 1.3.8) as a consumer property but could not find any way to set it up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not ask the same question in multiple places; it's a waste of your time and ours.

See [the boot documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.5.20.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-kafka-extra-props).

With 1.5, there is a general global `properties` property where you can set arbitrary properties (2.0 and later added general `properties` separately for consumers and producers).

`spring.kafka.properties.isolation.level=read_committed`

Comment: what will happen if the Consumer isolation level is set to "read_committed" , but the Producer doesnt use transactions ?

Comment: The consumer will receive non transactional records, regardless of isolation level.

Comment: @AshikaUmangaUmagiliya perhaps this will help. It has schematics explaining it from the consumer perspective. https://www.waitingforcode.com/apache-kafka/isolation-level-apache-kafka-consumers/read